# What is the average salary of a life sciences post doc in Singapore and what is the average living cost there?

Tags: postdocs, singapore

I am from India and I am about to submit my PhD thesis (Biotechnology) and considering for a post-doc in Singapore. Can you help me know what is the average post-doc salary in Singapore in an institute like NUS or TLL? From my contacts I have come to know that the cost of living in Singapore is quite high. Please guide me what would be the average monthly cost of  living for a family of 3 (me, my wife and an infant)?? or Should I look for a post-doc position in any other country like USA, UK, or anywhere in Europe?

Comment: I usually consider this site, but I have no idea if it is accurate for singapore.. http://www.numbeo.com/cost-of-living/city_result.jsp?country=Singapore&city=Singapore

Answer (score 1):

I have found that a good general source for salary information in [Glassdoor.com](https://www.glassdoor.com): everything on it should be taken with a grain of salt, but it's a good starting point for getting a general sense.  Searching there at the moment, postdocs in Singapore seem to be reporting around $5K/month.

Combining that with [the cost of living estimator recommended by Fabio Dias](http://www.numbeo.com/cost-of-living/city_result.jsp?country=Singapore&city=Singapore), it seems to be survivable, though you'll likely not be saving much.